# ruby hash params = [] params << {:param => :testString, type : :string}

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, types

I came across this code, cannot comprehend what it actually does. Could you please explain me what this does:

```
params = [] 
params << {:param => :testString, type : :string}
params << {:param => :testJson, type : :string}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is (you had the syntax mistake in your code):

```
params << {:param => :testString, type: :string}
# => [{:param=>:testString, :type=>:string}] 
params << {:param => :testJson, type: :string}
# => [{:param=>:testString, :type=>:string}, {:param=>:testJson, :type=>:string}]
```

The code just adds the `Hash` you defined into the `Array`. The method `<<` will append the specified value to the end of the `Array`, and it doesn't verify weither the value is already exists in the `Array`.

Please, don't mix old version of hash pair (using `=>`), and a new one (using `:`) because its view is very strange. So either:

```
params << {:param => :testString, type => :string}
```

or

```
params << {param: :testString, type: :string}
```

Comment: Thank Majioa, So is this same as the code pasted before, params = [] 
params << {:param => :testString, :type => :string}
params << {:param => :testJson, :type => :string}

Comment: @Swamy the code with a few changes before `:` the space has removed

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) method append an item to to the end of the array.

```
a = []
a << 1
a << 2
a # => [1, 2]
```

So the code adds two hash objects to the `params` array.

BTW, your hash literal causes a syntax error. Remove a space between `type` and `:`.

```
params << {:param => :testString, type : :string}
#                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details for the  [<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) (Push) method.

```
params = [] #instantiate new array named params
params << {:param => :testString, type: :string} #uses the << method to push a hash into the params array
params << {:param => :testJson, type: :string} #uses the << method to push a hash into the params array
```

The content of the params array will now be

```
[{:param => :testString, type: :string},{:param => :testJson, type: :string}]
```